# Halachot of IVF

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, jewish-books, medicine, pregnancy-birth

Does anyone know of any good teshuvas or sefers giving an overview of the halacha of in-vitro fertilization IVF?  (Feel free to also give overviews in your answers, but I'd appreciate links to the relevant opinions)

I'm looking for a sefer that would preferably address the circumstances under which one might use IVF, rules for IVF and passing parentage in halacha in cases of egg donation, rules of IVF surrogacy, permissibility of masturbation for purposes of IVF, and many other intricate halachic questions

Comment: I believe the _Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society_ had a major article on this; doubtless you can find it and see what sources it cites. Likewise, check _Nishmas Avraham_: see what sources he cites. (Not posting this as an answer, because I only have these secondary sources (and imprecise citations at that).)

Comment: At a shiur recently mention was made of teshuvos given by Rav Moshe Feinstein about this issue. Many references use the story of the birth of ben Sira who was fathered by the prophet Yirmiyahu by his being forced to ejaculate into a warm bath tub. While he was considered the father, he did not violate "having relations". I do not have the citations so this is only a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nishmat Avraham by Rabbi Dr Avraham Avraham is a classic and is available in Hebrew and English (Artscroll).

He discusses IVF quite a few times. In Vol 3, p15 he begins by quoting R' Waldenberg (Tzitz Eliezer 15:45) who doesn't approve, and then quotes R' Nebenzahl (Asya 34), R' Ovadia Yosef (Yabia Omer 8 EH 21) and R' Eliashiv who all permit AIH.

[Nishmas Avraham in Hebrew, older print](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51475&st=&pgnum=31)

It is also worthwhile reading Fred Rosner's '[Modern Medicine and Jewish Ethics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881250910)' p114-124 where he discusses this topic in much detail and discusses other ramifications including parenthood.

Comment: What is AIH? [15]

Comment: standard medical terminology for Artificial Insemination by Husband as opposed to AID (Artificial Insemination by Donor)

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, there are two more very relevant books on the topic in English. I read them both and they are excellent

- [Third Key: Jewish Guide to Fertility](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=CJmHbcrpq_cC&pg=PP4&lpg=PP4&dq=Third+Key:+Jewish+Guide+to+Fertility&source=bl&ots=LlnFUx60cv&sig=REn8wBESg2tixNRKbMlII82lNCI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61u2K8p7KAhVLaxQKHWRHB4gQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=Third%20Key%3A%20Jewish%20Guide%20to%20Fertility&f=false) by Baruch and Michal Finkelstein, with haskamot (approbations) from R Yisroel Belsky, R David Cohen (Brooklyn), R Zeev Leef. Relevant sections are those on assisted reproductive technology, halachic rulings for AIH and IVF and halachic aspects of third-party reproduction. Not available on amazon but apparently [here](http://www.eichlers.com/third-key-the-jewish-couples-guide-to-fertility-hardcover.html) or [here](http://zbermanbooks.com/third-key-jewish-guide-to-fertility)
- [Overcoming Infertility: A Guide For Jewish Couples](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592641067) by Richard Grazi which is stronger on the medical and ethical aspects but also has a section on halachic implications

The first one is the strongest in terms of halachic aspects and is highly recommended

Answer (score 2):

J david bleich, in his work ["Contemporary Halachik Problems, volume 4"](https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems%2C_Vol_IV%2C_Chapter_XI_In_Vitro_Fertilization%2C_Maternal_Identity_and_Conversion.1?lang=bi) deals with this at length. It can be found in the chapter "Chapter XI In Vitro Fertilization, Maternal Identity and Conversion".

Example:

> Although there is a minority view that regards the donor mother as the
> sole mother of a child born of in vitro fertilization,**2** the consensus
> of rabbinic opinion is that a maternal-filial relationship is
> generated between the gestational mother and the child, despite the
> absence of any genetic relationship, by virtue of parturition alone.
> Whether or not the genetic mother, i.e., the woman who produced the
> ovum from which the child was conceived, is also a mother from the
> vantage point of Jewish law is a more complex question. The question
> of whether the baby may, in effect, have two halakhic mothers must be
> regarded as yet open.
>
> 2. See R. Shlomoh Goren, Ha-Ẓofeh, 7 Adar I 5744. See also R. Joshua
>    Feigenbaum, Sha‘arei Torah, vol. IV, no. 4; Prof. Ze’ev Low, Emek
>    Halakhah, II (Jerusalem, 5749), 163–172; Dr. Itamar Warhaftig,
>    Teḥumin, V (5744), 268–269; and R. Ezra Bick, Teḥumin, VII (5746),
>    266–270.

Comment: It's on Sefaria. Want to provide a direct link? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Welcome @Josh to MY. Your answer would be improved by giving some sort of idea of what Rav Bleich says as well as a link to his content.