# Is altering human genetics wrong in Judaism?

Tags: halacha, medicine, pregnancy-birth, outer-space

So, our colonists of the oceanic planet Mayim (yes, that's its name), of whom every single one is a Jew, have encountered a problem: there is no more room on the buoyant-colony-thing that they live in, and they can't get back to Earth (the warp-gate broke).

Then the scientists have a great idea: their children shall become fish!

Seriously, gene modification so that everyone becomes parent to a blue fish mermaid/man, fins and everything. Mandatory for all. Is this morally wrong?

Important note: this is important for the to-be-born colonists' survival.

Another note: This isn't gene-splicing so much as going into the coding directly and messing around.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27107/1713

Comment: Considering we are gene splicing genetics from non kasher species into kasher species and calling it kasher to eat i'm not sure that there'd be an issue. But i don't think the big rabbis have finished weighing in on this particular issue yet

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for this thought-provoking question! We have a couple of somewhat-related questions about tinkering with the human reproduction on [three-parent children](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20265/sources-on-the-halachic-status-of-creating-three-parent-child)  and [IVF in general](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43703/halachot-of-ivf). I suggest that you [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name!

Comment: how much do we really understand genetics? it is a bottomless wisdom in my opinion

Comment: "Important note: this is important for the to-be-born colonists' survival." Generally except for the 3 cardinal sins, any prohibition is permitted in the face of risk to life. Assuming the situation is considered "risky" even if there were some prohibition, it would be permitted.