# How does creation of a new species of super humans align with Judaism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, science, latid-lavo-future, biology

One of the most promising scientific fields of the nearest future is bio-technologies especially genetic modifications, starting with [gene-therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_therapy), [genetic enhancements](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/283/5410/2023), and, as the process is completely unstoppable and uncontrollable, coming fast to [the attempts to create a new species of super humans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIIVh7H6nvI).

Definition: a new species is one that has distinctive features and can not interbreed with humans anymore.

As is seen from the question of "[any-reason-to-deny-aliens?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43835/is-there-any-reason-to-deny-aliens-according-to-judaism?) (*and other questions on Aliens and Judaism*) most Rabbis can not embrace an idea of the existence of a sentient species besides Homo Sapience.

Did our sources already speculate on how all this aligns with Judaism?

Comment: Humans are created with intelligence. If robots become smarter than people will they have a soul and the potential to develop one’s intellect? Should we be bothered by questions like these and leave it to G-d? Or should we embrace science as a commodity, a good. Your questions is thought-provoking and deserves a good answer.

Comment: As far as aliens go, Edward Snowden released new government files expressing that there is no collusion with aliens and the CIA. Aliens, IMHO, do not exist. I think humans, save G-d, is the greatest achievement of the universe. We may not be at the center of the universe but we sure act like it. In any event, let’s not ruin it by playing G-d and create killer-robots like the movie Terminator, Matrix, etc. Elon Musk is in agreement.

Comment: Contrary to some Talmudic writings, there is no mention of aliens in the Bible nor Deborah.

Comment: @TurkHill What Talmudic writings refer to aliens? It’s only post-Talmudic sources which claim that Meroz refers to aliens.

Comment: @DonielF You may be right actually. In any rate, there is no proof for aliens. None.

Comment: Is your question that the new "super-species" will technically be an intelligent, non-human race, like aliens?

Comment: They probably will produce a superhuman robot machine or new species.

Comment: I think we are all well aware of what happens when one group of beings incorrectly thinks of itself as genetically superior to other people. If people existed that really *were* genetically superior, the results could only be worse.

Comment: @RayButterworth I don't see why not - our genome is full of problems that lead to deceases and death, most of it can be solved in our lifetime. Those people can be 5 times healthier, 10 times stronger and live twice as long, just by having their genes tweaked.

Comment: @AlBerko, but what about people that aren't tweaked? A new improved species will see us inferiors as suitable for slave labour, service as humorous pets, or, if seen as potentially dangerous, extinction.  We could no longer breed freely, and certainly not by our own choice.  It nearly happened not long ago, and that was based on a lie; so consider a world in which the superiority were actually true and objectively justifiable, and based on species, not race. How do you feel right now about helping or allowing chimpanzees to establish their own growing and competing civilization?

Comment: @RayButterworth This discussion is not for this site. But the question is not whether but when.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64014/

Comment: Can golems be considered artificial super-humans?

Answer (score 1):

Some genetic alternation is allowed (adviced, even), for avoiding unwanted traits:

> בכורות מה ב
>
> אמר ר"ל גבוה לא ישא גבוהית שמא יצא מהן תורן ננס לא ישא ננסת שמא יצא
>   מהם אצבעי לבן לא ישא לבנה שמא יצא מהם בוהק שחור לא ישא שחורה שמא יצא
>   מהן טפוח

Bechorot 45:b

Reish Lakish said: Tall man shouldn't marry tall woman, for their child might be "flagpole" (child with excessive height).
Short man shouldn't marry short woman, for their child might be "finger-sized" (very short child).
White man shouldn't marry white woman, for their child might be "glitter" (child with extreme white skin).
Black man shouldn't marry black woman, for their child might be "pot-coal" (child with extreme dark skin).

How much more so, to avoid actual genetic-disease.

About actually improving the children attributes ("super-humans"):

בבא מציעא פד א

ר' יוחנן הוה אזיל ויתיב אשערי טבילה אמר כי סלקן בנות ישראל מטבילת מצוה לפגעו בי כי היכי דלהוו להו בני שפירי כוותי גמירי אורייתא כוותי

Baba metzia 84:a

R' Yochanan walked and set near the gates of the Mikve, he said when the Israeli women will return from the ceremonial bating (therefore they about to have intercourse with their husbands), they will encounter me, so that they will have sons as beautiful as me, and talented at Tora learning like me.

[It was believed that looking at people effect the attributes of the infant, see Gitin 58:a].

R' Yochanan wasn't just pretty, he had inhuman beauty!!

ברכות ה ב

> רבי יוחנן חזא דהוה קא גני בבית אפל גלייה לדרעיה ונפל נהורא חזייה

Berchot 5:b

Rabbi Yochanan saw that Rabbi Eliezer was sleeping in a dark house. He exposed he's arm and the house became lit.

Comment: Rabbi Yochanan and Reish Lakish were friends, and they both concerned about the traits of the following generation...coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Bible in general and Genesis 1:27 in particular, Adam was the first human ever created. Adam means man because he was the first person to have a soul (or in Hebrew שפנ), the neshama. That is not to say that Adam was the first Homo sapiens. Adam and Eve had a mother and a father like you and me.

**What did Maimonides and Nahmanides say**

Maimonides in The Guide for the Perplexed (part 1 chapter 7) explains that ainamls co-existed with Adam; identical in shape and remarkably intelligent, but lacked the neshama. This made these people animals, respectfully. Seven centuries before Darwin, cave men (pre-Adam hominids) walked with Adam. Genesis 1:26, G-d says “Let us make Adam.” In the following verse, G-d creates “the Adam,” the Adam, a new kind of man [a nuance in the text]. This nuance does not exist in the English translation of the text; only in Hebrew.

Additionally, the Mishna mentions “masters of the field” and explains that these "masters" were not people; but animals identical to humans, which implies farming and cultivating the land that pre-dates the Adam of Genesis. Now you have agriculture pre-dating Adam?

Nahmanides a kabalistic commentator discuss Genesis 2:7, explaining that Adam became a man when G-d infused the soul into his body. The Ramban calls this change, “another kind of man.”[1] What is this change?

**Does the Bible mention this change?**

Yes. Genesis 2:7 reads:

> “The L-rd G-d formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a nefesh chayah.”

Onkelos does not render this simply as “a living being,” but characterizes this as man's ruach m’mal’la, “one with the power of speech,” a phrase denoting a certain level of intelligence.

**What about the Cave men?**

Although people have been farming for thousands of years, Adam was the first person with actual intelligence. Maybe an inventor of some sort. Cain, his son would go on to build a city.[2] Now you have civisilation. The problem lies in the mistakable term of Cave men. The wrong assumption lies in the "men," they were not men until G-d gave Adam a soul.

**The future?**

If scientists someday generate new human bioelectronic species (machine-like) in the form of terminators, it will not pose a threat. Robots have no emotion and are not afraid of death. Therefore, the robot is deprived of its soul. They are intelligent and thus may not be animals, but will lack consciousness. Adam was given a soul, in addition to everything else that machines could not have, despite the superiority of intelligence.

[1] It is noteworthy to mention here that G-d made only one kind of man, not two. After Adam G-d never made a "new kind" of man. Thus, Jews and non-Jews share the same soul.

[2] Historians have noted that little farming communities existed for thousands of years and that people could have been on this earth for millions; but cities did not appear until about 5,000 years ago, the time of the creation of Adam in the Bible.

Comment: "Adam and Eve had a mother and a father like you and me." Source???

Comment: @IsraelReader from Rabbi Michael Laitman's Kabbalist blog.

Comment: ערבך ערבא צריך. Do you have a source from Chazal, or traditional, canonical commentaries?

Answer (score 0):

The premise behind this question is questionable. While some Rabbis may be of the opinion there is no life on other planets I doubt any of them would view their opinion on the issue  as one of the Ikerey Emunah.

Assuming a new species that has distinctive features and can not interbreed with humans but can breed with other creatures like it and isn't just a high tech machine is created (I'll believe it when I see it.Scientists have been making false promises of imminently creating such a thing for decades already) depending on how it was created it would probably fall into one three categories discussed in traditional Jewish sources (1)If it was created through  genetic engineering then it would be Kilayim of whatever its original components were (2)golem (3)sheidim. Not real sheidim because people can't possibly create them but something of that nature and status.

It would be similar to the halachic question of is a genetically altered chicken kosher?